# Finding i-th row in a matrix in wolfram mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have trying to multipy a column matrix and a row matrix in mathematica. But mathematica gives row matrix as a column matrix. so multipy function doesnt work. My codes are

```
`Y = Inverse[S];
Print["Y=", MatrixForm[Y]];
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
Subscript[P, i] = MatrixForm[S[[All, i]].Y[[i]]];
Print["CarpimS=", MatrixForm[S[[All, i]]]];
Print["CarpimY=", MatrixForm[Y[[i]]]];
Print["P=", Subscript[P, i]];
];
```

If anyone know this situation please answer

Comment: a bit of an aside to your question, but you rarely if ever assign something equal to an output form, ie do `Subscript[P, i] = S[[All, i]].Y[[i]];` , then apply the `MatrixForm` where needed in the `Print` statement.  (of course here the `Dot` produces a scalar so its not needed. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a badly written question, so I'm going to have to make some guesses.  Your code does not seem relevant to your question, with this exception: `S[[All, i]].Y[[i]]`. Given your description, I'm guessing we can say that `S` is k by k and so is `Y`.  If your goal is to `Dot` the i-th column of `S` by the i-th row of its inverse `Y`, then what you have is fine: you produce each as a 1-d vector, and then produce a scalar product.  But you say you're not getting what you want, so I'm guessing you want the outer product instead.

```
mS = IdentityMatrix[5];
mS[[3, 3]] = 99;
mY = Inverse[mS];
mS[[All, 3]].mY[[3]]  (* scalar product *)
Outer[Times, mS[[All, 3]], mY[[3]]] (* outer product *)
```

If I guessed wrong, you will have to work on improving your question.

Comment: Alan thank you so much from Turkey :) outer product solved my problem. I might have written my question bad, but your guesses solved my problem. Using the scalar product was the main problem in my codes.